# Problems running a test site

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I'm new with Python > Django.
I have problems running a hello world page on my test website.
I'm using pythonanywhere.com to make a test site.

I created the site folder and the app folder correctly using these commands:

```
django-admin startproject website
python manage.py startapp music
```

Now to show a hello world page i opened the website urls.py and wrote these lines:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
]
```

music/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

music/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse #corrected thanks but don't works anyway

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

When I visit mysite.com/music/ I see a 404 error page. Why?

Comment: how do you run your project?

Comment: Well django doesn't have a `httpresponse` class.... it has a `HttpResponse` class, so either you need to use the correct casing or include the actual code you're using.

Comment: You can't run a Django site just by uploading some code to a hosting service. You need to have some kind of webserver running - usually via WSGI - and configure the host to actually use it. So, as Bear says, how are you running this project?

Comment: thank you but with the correct case HttpResponse it always show a 404 error page.
I'm using pythonanywhere.com to run my website. It is a remote server.

Comment: Did you read my comment at all?

Comment: @DanielRoseman https://www.pythonanywhere.com/details/django_hosting may clarify a few points on the server issue.

Comment: @Pierino this may be highly dependent on how PythonAnywhere sets up their Django integration. Is there a debug option, that shows you whether your request to mysite.com/music/ actually passes through Django, or whether the webserver immediately returns a 404?

Comment: From the PythonAnywhere forum page: "We also monitor StackExchange for questions about PythonAnywhere, so feel free to ask technical questions over there too.". You may want to add another tag to your question.

Comment: I tried also as the documentation saying but I've always failed. I have to retry and retry :( (pythonanywhere tag added)

Comment: I'm receiving these errors with the wsgi.py file when I try to deploy my site: https://pastebin.com/0HRgXjGu

Comment: Do you have a package called mysite on your sys.path. See http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/ for details about debugging this.

Answer (score 1):

Having a django project in a folder of your host server is not enough, you have to configure the front HTTP server (Apache, Nginx or whatever is running on your host server) to serve your project. How to do so depends on the front server and host, so [the best here is to refer to pythonanyware's documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject).

Now a server is not the right place to work on your project - the usual workflow is "develop locally, deploy, lather/rinse/repeat". Django comes with a [builtin dev server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server) so you don't even have to configure anything more (and you have automagical code reloading on code changes which saves a lot of time).

Answer (score 1):

Locally, you can easily run the project by running the following command from your dajngo project folder.

`python manage.py runserver`

To run django Project from pythonanywhere, check the following doc - https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/